# Searching through .txt files using regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex, twitter, bigdata

I have an unformatted list of tweets (just copy-pasted from the website *en masse*), and I'm trying to separate each tweet in to its own individual line while taking out all the other extraneous detail in the text file.

I currently have a regex string that works when I search through in notepad++, but for some reason I can't get it to work through C++.

an example of the text I am searching through is as follows:

```
Autotestdrivers.com ‏@testdrivernews Nov 6

Tesla Model S third row of seats confuses,… http://dlvr.it/CgTbsL  #children #models #police #tesla #teslamotors #Autos #Car #Trucks

1 retweet 3 likes

Gina Stark ✈ ‏@SuuperG Nov 6

Ha! Kinda. @PowayAutoRepair I have a thing for "long-nose" cars; #Porsche #Jaguar #Ferrari , and I love the lines of a #Tesla!

View conversation

0 retweets 2 likes

Tony Morice ‏@WestLoopAuto Nov 6

\#WeirdCarNews via @Therealautoblog  Tesla Model S third row of seats confuses, delights police http://www.autoblog.com/2015/11/06/tesla-model-s-third-row-seats-police/ …

View summary

0 retweets 0 likes
```

The regex i am using takes the date the tweet was posted and the tweet itself, and looks like this:

```
[A-Z][a-z][a-z] \d+\r\n\r\n *.+\r\n
```

...but for some reason, I cannot get it to work in my code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

std::regex rgx("[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\\d+\\r\\n\\r\\n *.+\\r\\n");

    std::string Location_Of_Tweet = "put location here";
    std::smatch match;
    std::cout << twitterFile;

    std::ifstream twitterFiler;

    twitterFiler.open(Location_Of_Tweet,std::ifstream::in);

    const std::string tweetFile((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(twitterFiler)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    if (std::regex_search(tweetFile.begin(), tweetFile.end(), match, rgx))
    {
        std::cout << "Match\n";

        for (auto m : match)
         std::cout << "  submatch " << m << '\n';
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No match\n";
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about _"i cannot get it to work in my code"_ please? What's the specific problem? Compiler error? Runtime error? Unexpected results? Post a [MCVE] please, including all of the error messages verbaitm.

Comment: sorry about being unclear. the code does compile and run, the only issue that I'm having is that the regex is not finding any matches (which i know are in the .txt file). I edited the code for completeness.

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using? E.g. GCC 4.8 still had problems with the `std::regex` implementation. Also the sample code you show wouldn't even compile if someone else want's to test it.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015 to create and compile all my code currently.

Comment: Can you post a sample date that your regex should match ? Have you checked the line terminators, there are different conventions ( namely, `\n` on *nix/linux, `\r\n` on Windows, iirc `\n\r` on some versions of MacOS) ?

Comment: I just figured it out after quite a bit of messing around with the c++ escape conventions. the final regex that i used was `[A-Z][a-z][a-z] \\d+\\\n\\\n *.+ \\\n`. Because the code was reading in the `\n` directly, i needed to detect that as plaintext instead of an actual line break of any sort. `\r\n` was used in notepad++ searching, which is one of the things that threw me off.

Comment: @collapsar - `'\n'` is a newline on all platforms. The fact that Windows puts two bytes into a file when you write `'\n'` doesn't change that. It matters if you're reading the file as binary, but as text the standard library takes care of that adjustment.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex assumes c++11 regex understands horizontal whitespace `\h`.
If not, replace all `\h` with `[^\S\r\n]`.

This is loosly interpreted as what might work.
But, you would need a more substantial delimiter to separate the tweets.

`"(?m)([A-Z][a-z][a-z]\\h+\\d+)\\h*\\r?\\n\\s*^\\h*(?=\\S)(.+)"`

Explained

```
 (?m)                               # Multi-line mode
 ( [A-Z] [a-z] [a-z] \h+ \d+ )      # (1), Date
 \h* \r? \n \s*                     # Line break, any number of whitespace
 ^ \h*                              # Beginning of line
 (?= \S )                           # Next, first non-whitespace
 ( .+ )                             # (2), Tweet
```

Test Case using your sample.
Output

```
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 37 , len 5 ) 
Nov 6  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 46 , len 132 ) 
Tesla Model S third row of seats confuses,… http://dlvr.it/CgTbsL  #children #models #police #tesla #teslamotors #Autos #Car #Trucks  

-----------------

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 226 , len 5 ) 
Nov 6  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 235 , len 126 ) 
Ha! Kinda. @PowayAutoRepair I have a thing for "long-nose" cars; #Porsche #Jaguar #Ferrari , and I love the lines of a #Tesla!  

-----------------

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 435 , len 5 ) 
Nov 6  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 444 , len 170 ) 
\#WeirdCarNews via @Therealautoblog  Tesla Model S third row of seats confuses, delights police http://www.autoblog.com/2015/11/06/tesla-model-s-third-row-seats-police/ …
```